# Cauchy product of Three Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

We know the Cauchy product of two series $\big( \sum_n a_n \big) \big(\sum_n b_n \big) = \sum_j c_j$ where $c_j = \sum_{k=0}^j a_jb_{k-j}$. How do I write the Cauchy product of three series $\big( \sum_n a_n \big) \big(\sum_n b_n \big) \big(\sum_n c_n \big)$?

I tried $\big(\sum_n a_n \big)\Big[ \big(\sum_n b_n \big)\big(\sum_n c_n \big)\Big]$ and using the Cauchy product inside the big bracket and then distribute $a_n$ inside but then it became a mess. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "We know the product of two series..."  , actually no, we don't know that at all, there are infinitely many way of defining products of series, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871203/how-to-multiply-two-infinite-series-correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the most clean way is

$$
\big( \sum_n a_n \big) \big(\sum_n b_n \big)\big( \sum_n c_n \big) = \sum_k d_k
$$
where
$$
d_k=\sum_{i+j+l=k}a_ib_jc_l
$$