# Product of corresponding terms in two Infinite series

Tags: real-analysis

> Given two series (over complex numbers) that are convergent but not absolutely convergent:
>
> $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = K_0$
>
> $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n = K_1$
>
> (where $K_0$ and $K_1$ are some real numbers)
>
> Now, let us consider the series arising from the dot product
>
> $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n*b_n = Sum_0$
>
> (where $Sum_0$ is equal the sum of infinite terms in the series)
>
> **Can we comment something on the value of $Sum_0$?**

I read the **Cauchy Product** ([How to Multiply Two Infinite Series Correctly?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871203/how-to-multiply-two-infinite-series-correctly))  but that deals with all terms in first series being multiplied with all terms in second series where as we are restricted to a subset of multiplying only corresponding terms in both series. So that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Well, the product  (in the sense you specify) doesn't even need to converge.  Say $a_n=b_n=\frac {(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}$.

Comment: It could also be zero if $a_n$ is zero on odd integers and $b_n$ on even integers. I don't think you can say anything about it.

Comment: Thank you. As a follow up: in case, if both $k_0$ and $K_1$ are 0, still its unanswerable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am fairly sure that nothing can be said about your product series; consider the sequences below with $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\beta_1,\beta_2,C_0,C_1\in\mathbb{C}$:
$$
a_n = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \alpha_1 & \quad n=-3 \\
0 & \quad n=-2 \\
\alpha_2 & \quad n=-1 \\
            0 & \quad n=2k\geq0 \\
            \frac{C_0}{k^2} & \quad n=2k+1\geq1
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
$$
b_n = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \beta_1 & \quad n=-3 \\
\beta_2 & \quad n=-2 \\
0 & \quad n=-1\\
            \frac{C_1}{k^2} & \quad n=2k\geq0 \\
            0 & \quad n=2k+1\geq1 
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
Then each series ($\sum a_n$, $\sum b_n$, and $\sum a_n\cdot b_n$) can be made to converge absolutely to any three complex numbers you wish, even in the case that you wish to force the first two series to be $0$.

One of the comments on the OP also demonstrates that the product series need not converge at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand the general point, but i am unsure about the case (0, 0). If at all possible, can you please help with a an example/argument?

Comment: @TheoryQuest1 Sorry, I may have made a typo, so I have just gone and made the answer even more carefully constructed. Now, you use $\alpha_2$ to cancel the contribution of the $C_0/k^2$ part, subtract $\epsilon$ from $\alpha_2$ and add it to $\alpha_1$. Do the same thing to $\beta_1$, $C_1/k^2$, and $\beta_2$. Now, your two original series sum absolutely to $0$, but the product series sums to $\epsilon^2$. Every complex number has a "square root", and then we are done.