# Results about dot products of two series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose I have sums $A= \sum_i a_i$ and $B= \sum_i b_i$, and I define a product $A *B= \sum_i a_i b_i$, then are there results on:

1. Relating convergence of $A$ and $B$ to that of $A*B$?
2. Relating boundedness?
3. Anything else, if somehow related to the above two concepts?

Comment: Hmm . Close votes without any explanation. I don't understand what the problem with this question is..

Comment: I believe you need absolute convergence for one of the sums in order to have the dot product converge.

Comment: Not my close vote, but this is an extremely unfocused question, and you've given zero evidence of having tried to figure out anything on your own.

Comment: What would constitute as me trying to figure out something on my own here? I haven't seen any book discuss results related to this topic in my readings, so I don't even have a starting point. If you search up "product of series" on google,  then most probably you would find something about cauchy product than this.@JonathanZsupportsMonicaC

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3041681/product-of-corresponding-terms-in-two-infinite-series

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4060568/show-inner-product-of-two-infinite-sums-is-convergent-or-divergent

Answer (score 2):

I do not have the ability to comment, but the comment above is incorrect.  As a counter-example, consider $A = B = \sum_n 1/n$ for which $A*B = \sum_n 1/n^2$ does converge.  Neither sum absolutely converge, but their "product" does.