# RCA Rudin: What role does absolute convergence play in computation here?

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I don't understand why Rudin said *The absolute convergence of (1) shows that the computation is correct* here, I think I can do this computation without absolute convergence?

[How to Multiply Two Infinite Series Correctly?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871203/how-to-multiply-two-infinite-series-correctly)

Comment: rearranging the summands (first equal sign).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Sorry, I still not quite understand why I need that property?

Comment: Look up the Riemann rearrangement theorem. This is all standard stuff covered in analysis texts, and since you mention Rudin, look at PMA, particularly theorems 3.50, 3.54 (in fact, just read everything from the section on absolute convergence onwards).

Comment: In fact, if you think this is so easy to do without absolute convergence, try to prove it. If you manage to give a “proof”, then go read what I mentioned above, and then find the mistake in your “proof”. This will be a very useful exercise in gaining familiarity with limits, series and definitions.

Comment: I like this video @TerryYoung. There is a brief discussion of what you are asking (among many other things): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JOg9kQp7pig&list=PLw3pvR_YJeRcMaubDZvkjayqDJT4Tx47A&index=4